# ProxyHTMLURLMap not modifying JavaScript file

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache2, mod-proxy

I'm using Apache 2.4.27 as a Reverse Proxy and I am having trouble with some of my ProxyHTMLURLMap directives.

I have a *proxy-server* and a backend server, called *server1*.

I have a JavaScript fragment appear in an HTML as well as a separate JS file.  The ProxyHTMLURLMap incorrectly modifies the HTML file, and does not modify the JS file.

How do I define this URLMap to affect both places?

Here's my config fragment:

```
LogLevel warn proxy_html:trace3

<Location "/server1/">
    ProxyPass https://server1:5443/ ping=2
    ProxyPassReverse https://server1/

    ProxyHTMLEnable On
    ProxyHTMLExtended On

    SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE

    ProxyHTMLURLMap /rpc/ /server1/rpc/
</Location>
```

The JavaScript fragment that appears in both HTML and JS files is:

```
abc.get({
    url: "/rpc/getdefaultcfg.asp",
    onrcv: function(arg) {
        if (arg.STATUS == 0) {
            default_Lang = WEBVAR_JSONVAR_GETDEFAULTLANG.WEBVAR_STRUCTNAME_GETDEFAULTLANG;
        }
        onload = loadInit();
    }
});
```

The HTML file is modified by the ProxyServer *twice* by updating the matching line to:

```
url: "/server1/server1/rpc/getdefaultcfg.asp",
```

Notice the duplicate "server1".  Why is it being duplicated?

This HTML file includes the JS file as follows:

```
<script language="Javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

However, the index.js does not get modified by the proxy server.  It remains untouched as:

```
url: "/rpc/getdefaultcfg.asp",
```

Why is the JS file untouched by the URLMap directive?  Any ideas much appreciated!

FYI, the httpd_access_log file shows the 404 errors on line 2 and 5 below:

```
1. 192.1.0.76 - "GET /server1/index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 946
2. 192.1.0.76 - "GET /rpc/getdefaultcfg.asp HTTP/1.1" 404 223
3. 192.1.0.76 - "GET /server1/page/disable_javascript.html HTTP/1.1" 200 212
4. 192.1.0.76 - "GET /server1/page/blank.html HTTP/1.1" 200 -
5. 192.1.0.76 - "GET /server1/server1/rpc/getdefaultcfg.asp HTTP/1.1" 404 126
```

Finally, the output from proxy_html tracing:

```
[proxy_html:trace3] mod_proxy_html.c(265): [client 192.1.0.76:51880] C: matched /rpc/, substituting /server1/rpc/
[proxy_html:trace3] mod_proxy_html.c(265): [client 192.1.0.76:51880] C: matched /rpc/, substituting /server1/rpc/
[proxy_html:trace1] mod_proxy_html.c(827): [client 192.1.0.76:51880] Non-HTML content; not inserting proxy-html filter, referer: https://proxy-server/server1/page/header.html
[proxy_html:trace1] mod_proxy_html.c(827): [client 192.1.0.76:51880] Non-HTML content; not inserting proxy-html filter, referer: https://proxy-server/server1/page/header.html
[proxy_html:trace1] mod_proxy_html.c(827): [client 192.1.0.76:51892] Non-HTML content; not inserting proxy-html filter, referer: https://proxy-server/server1/page/login.html
[proxy_html:trace1] mod_proxy_html.c(827): [client 192.1.0.76:51892] Non-HTML content; not inserting proxy-html filter, referer: https://proxy-server/server1/page/login.html
[proxy_html:trace1] mod_proxy_html.c(827): [client 192.1.0.76:51880] Non-HTML content; not inserting proxy-html filter, referer: https://proxy-server/server1/page/header.html
[proxy_html:trace1] mod_proxy_html.c(827): [client 192.1.0.76:51880] Non-HTML content; not inserting proxy-html filter, referer: https://proxy-server/server1/page/header.html
```

Matt.

Answer (score 1):

I found the `ProxyHTMLURLMap` directive lacked the flexibility I needed with the substitutions.  Instead I used the `Substitute` directive.

To ensure the substitutions occurred in each of the file types I cared about, I first used the following directive:

```
     AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/javascript text/html text/css
```

Then I used many `Substitute` directives. An example of one of those is:

```
    # Fixup min.js urlPath() references
    Substitute "s#(urlPath\(\))#$1 + \"$npar/\" #q"
```

One thing to note is that the whole file is scanned for each `Substitute` directive, so try to cram as many substitutions as you can into one.  For example, I used regex to cover several cases:

```
    Substitute "s#(\"|\')/(api|app|images|source|style)#$1/$npar/$2#q"
```

If you have a big file, and lots of individual `Substitute` directives, then the performance penalty is significant!

Matt.

Answer (score 0):

One down, one to go.  I discovered the fix for one of my questions, duplicate substitutions...  In brief, this is bad:

```
ProxyHTMLEnable On
SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
```

Both directives insert proxy-html filter provider into the Output Filter chain.  Apparently, at one time, ProxyHTMLEnable did not insert proxy-html, so the second line was needed.

No more duplicates, once I corrected the 2nd line to be:

```
ProxyHTMLEnable On
SetOutputFilter INFLATE;DEFLATE
```

For completeness, an equivalent would be:

```
ProxyHTMLEnable Off
SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
```

Matt.

Comment: Did you solve the 2nd problem?

Comment: Yes I did.  I added that content in a separate answer.